# Retrieve ATI GPU info (memory, GPU load and so on) on OSX via python

Tags: python

I am trying to collect info about my video card to profile it, while running my python application; although I can't find any python module that is able to do so.

On Windows I have been using `GPUtil`, with my Nvidia card and it works great; but my mac has an ATI card. I tried also `pyadl` but it require `ADLSDK3.0`, which from what I can tell is windows only, not OSX.

At this point I am stuck; can't use GPUtil, can't use pyadl and can't find anything similar to GPUtil; which is a great library but sadly is Nvidia only.

Comment: what specific information are you trying to gather about your video card?

Comment: I would like to retrieve total VRAM, currently used VRAM, free VRAM and GPU load in percentage